# get the keyword from input box and pass it to the url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a search form that get results from a feed based on the user's keyword and the feed source. But I have no idea how to pass the user's search term from the input box to the selected feed url in the data-source attribute. I was told that I can't just dump the js variable in the html markup. Is there no choice but to repeat the ajax function for each feed? Any help would be appreciated.

HTML markup

```
<select id="choosefeed">
 <option value="">Select</option>
 <option data-source="http://search.com?query='keyword variable'">Feed1</option>
 <option data-source="http://find.com?query='keyword variable'&result=25">Feed2</option>
</select>
<input id="input_id" type="text"><button type="submit" id="keywordsubmit">Submit</button>
<div id="searcharea"></div>
```

JS script

```
$('#keywordsubmit').click(function(e){

 var findsource = $('#choosefeed').find(':selected');
 var source = findsource.data('source');
 var keyword = $('#input_id').val();
 var area = $("#searcharea");
 area.empty();

 $.ajax({
        url: source,
        success: function (data) {
 ................
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [**.replace()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
var source = findsource.data('source').replace('keyword variable', $('#input_id').val());
```

However You can use `data` option of [**jQuery.ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to pass value.